# I am unable to load the table view cell inside the table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class NewOrdersViewControllers: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var items = ["Chilli and Lemon"]
    @IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblRestaurantNames: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: UIButton!

    var cellIdentifier = "cell"

    init() {
        super.init(nibName : "NewOrdersViewControllers", bundle:nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "tableCell", bundle: nil)

        self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func mapPush(sender: AnyObject) {


        let mapVC = MapViewController()

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapVC, animated: true)
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:tableCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! tableCell

        //cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row] as! String

        cell.RestaurantLbl.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 100
    }
```

I have done it using xib and it shows the following error.

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1fe82bc)

Comment: please make class names start with an upper case letter : `TableCell`. Have you correctly set up the cell with the correct identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: where  are defining cellIdentifier ?

Comment: `tableCell` is your class of table view cell?

Comment: change var cellIdentifier = "cell" to value which you set in cell xib as reuseidentifier

Comment: I am also using xib and getting the same error message.

Comment: See my solution below, if it solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad()` method you register 2 different cell types for the same `reuseIdentifier`, so the last one (`UITableViewCell`) takes effect. That's why in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the cells being dequeued are also of `UITableViewCell` class and may not be cast to your custom cell class.

Try to remove the line:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

it should fix your problem and let the `tableView` dequeue the correct cells.

Comment: I have tried it but it shows the following error message - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.' @maxkonolov

Comment: @RakeshMohan make sure your xib is set up correctly: the root object must be a `UITableViewCell` with its `class` set to your custom cell subclass. To be 100% sure, you can try creating a new Cocoa Touch class, making it a `UITableViewCell` subclass and checking "Also create XIB file" option. That way Xcode will wire up everything as needed for you.